# solr ignores values in multifield search

Tags: solr, tokenize, solrj

I have just started using Solr and I am not sure what I am missing. I have 2 fields streetAddresses and cities. streetAddresses is text field and cities is string field. This is already been configured before I started looking at Solr. The schema.xml for the fields look like

```
<types>
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.TextField" name="TextField">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
<fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.StrField" name="StrField"/>
</types>
<fields>
 <field indexed="true" multiValued="true" name="streetAddresses" stored="true" type="TextField"/>
 <field docValues="true" indexed="true" multiValued="true" name="cities" stored="true" type="StrField"/>
</fields>
```

The issue is when I query multiple field the parsed string for streetAddresses has only first part of the string and the rest is ignored. For example if I search the streetAddresses for 111 Main St and cities for Boston, the query looks like

```
q=streetAddresses%3A111+Main+st+OR+cities%3ABoston&wt=json&indent=true&debugQuery=true&defType=edismax&qf=streetAddresses%2Ccities
```

And the debug looks like

```
"rawquerystring": "streetAddresses:111 Main st OR cities:Boston",
"querystring": "streetAddresses:111 Main st OR cities:Boston",
"parsedquery": "(+(streetAddresses:111 cities:Boston))/no_coord",
"parsedquery_toString": "+(streetAddresses:111 cities:Boston)",
"explain": {},
"QParser": "ExtendedDismaxQParser",
"altquerystring": null,
"boost_queries": null
```

I am getting the result based on 111 for the streetAddresses but the rest of the string (Main st) is ignored. I tried to search for the issue and some have mentioned about stopwords or wordlimit but I do not use any of that. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
streetAddresses:111 Main st OR cities:Boston
```

means "search for `111` in streetAddresses, `Main` in the default search field (.. which may not be set by default any longer), `st` in the default search field, and for `Boston` in `cities`.

If you want to search for `111 Main st` in `streetAddresses`, you'll have to quote the value (and use a phrase search):

```
streetAddresses:"111 Main st"
```

.. or specify the field each time:

```
streetAddresses:111 streetAddresses:Main streetAddresses:st
```

Comment: Then why it is not the same case if I just search by streetAddresses. query:q=streetAddresses%3A111+Main+St&wt=json&indent=true&debugQuery=true&defType=edismax&qf=streetAddresses and "parsedquery_toString": "+(streetAddresses:111 (streetAddresses:main) (streetAddresses:st))". Another issue with usingquotes is I will not be able to use wildcard character, correct?

Comment: If you compare the two queries, the second one requires a hit for `main` as well - it's not being parsed the same way. You can use a complex phrase query if you need `*`, but maybe you don't want a tokenized type in that case at all?

Comment: So you are saying I do not need StandardTokenizerFactory? If I understand correctly, I think so too. The scenario is if I search for 111 Main St, I want to see documents with 111 Main St and I may also use a wildcard like 111 Main*.Ideally I need to learn how Solr scoring works because we may need to  search 111(OR)Main(OR)St but for now do you think the best way is to do like {!complexphrase inOrder=true}address:"111 Main*"?

Comment: For that case, use a KeywordTokenizer with a LowercaseFilter. It'll keep the entire text as a single token, and lowercase it as well. Wildcard search should do what you want then, be sure to escape the spaces with `\\`.

Comment: Yes I thought that was the answer but the issue is there is also a name field which is also text same as address. The only difference is that the user also wants to search by lastname,firstname. From my understanding keyword tokenizer does not work well with punctuation comma and also reverse order. So left the choice. In case of I want to use keyword tokenizer is it possible to update the tokenizer of field using schema API curl command and do I need to reload data?

Comment: Use multiple fields - different fields for different use cases. One field can use the `KeywordTokenizer`, another can use a regular tokenizer such as whitespace or standard (but don't use a wildcarded search against those, as that will skip analysis). You can change the tokenizer through the Schema API, and you have to reindex your content after changing the tokenizer or analysis chain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172519/discussion-between-raghul-raman-and-matslindh).